# Using netcat to wait neo to be ready within the same container

Tags: docker, neo4j, netcat

So consider the following... If we had a docker container called app, this app contained an instance of neo4j database. Within the Dockerfile under the CMD we reference entrypoint.sh. From this script we are running the following ...

```
end="$((SECONDS+60))"
while true; do
    nc -z localhost 7687 && break
    [[ "${SECONDS}" -ge "${end}" ]] && exit 1
    sleep 1
done
```

The question is why does netcat not see the neo, even though it is booting. I have confirmed this by commenting out the CMD line within the dockerfile and checking that we can get to it though a browser.

If there is only one container enclosing neo and netcat running within the entrypoint.sh will it even have access to neo when it comes up or would netcat need to be in a seperate container all together ?

My docker-compose.yaml is below...

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: neo4j-ingestion
    expose:
      - "7474"
      - "7687"
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "7474:7474"
    environment:
      MEMORY_LOCK: "true"
      DB_START_DELAY: "10"
      PROCESSORS: "2"
      DATA_INGEST_FOLDER: /ingest/pending
      NEO4J_AUTH: "neo4j/password"
      NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT: "yes"
      NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize: "4G"
      NEO4J_HOSTNAME: "0.0.0.0"
      NEO4J_USERNAME: "neo4j"
      NEO4J_PASSWORD: "password"
      PROCESS_NAME: "neo4j-ingest"
      INGESTION_TYPE: "incremental"
      SLEEP_PERIOD: "20"
      CREATE_SCHEMA: "false"
      NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: "apoc.*"
      IS_DELTA: "1"

    volumes:
      - neodata:/data
      - "./test-integration/incremental:/ingest"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1

volumes:
  neodata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: What starts the database?  Can you show that code?  Why are you trying to run multiple things in the same container?  (...though you will need a similar wait loop in any case.)

Comment: The database is started by as part of the DockerFile, it is based on the neo4j-enterprise 3.5 image with some custom apk installs and persmission changes. The usual stuff, might be a bit difficult to show that as it is business sensitive. Is it not a clever idea to run it like this ?

Comment: Docker images don't persist running processes, so if you're doing something like `RUN service ... start` it doesn't actually start the database.  In general I would not try to run things besides the database in a database container, though.